# C: deep copying - structure with a void pointer

Tags: c, data-structures, memcpy, void-pointers

I've got a following struct

```
struct teststruct
{
int *a;
void *data;      
};
```

Is it possible to do a deep copy of structure which contains a void pointer? I assume that I cannot tell how many bytes `data` pointer points to? So I cannot malloc specified number of bytes and do memcpy. Am I right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Since you do not know the type that the void* points to, a deep copy is out of the question.

In addition, you could not even deep copy `a` since it may point to either a single `int` ot an array of them.

Typically in C, you would have a structure which carries the data types of it's contents if you wished to be able to do deep copies. For example:

```
struct teststruct {
    int a_sz;
    enum voidType vt;
    int *a;
    void *data;      
};
```

Then you could use `a_sz` to figure out how many integers the memory pointed to by `a` was composed of and the enumerated type of `data`, although technically it could also be an array so you may need a `d_sz` as well.

Another trick is to have `data` point to a structure that carries it's own data type embedded in it, such as:

```
typedef struct {
    enum voidType vt;
    union {
        int i;
        float f;
        double d;
    }
} tVoidType;
```

Answer (score 5):

If you have no information on the size of the data pointed to by `void *data` I would say you cannot successfully deep copy this struct.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct, you cannot tell how many bytes have been allocated for `data`. In fact, you can't even be sure that `data` points to `malloc()`ed memory; it could be pointing to anything on the heap, stack, or global space.

Even if you *could* find out the size of the data, you still cannot know the *structure* of the internal data, which means that a proper "deep copy" would not be possible. A deep copy wouldn't stop at the first pointer depth.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, but please distinguish: you can make a deep copy, but you can not tell on how many bytes pointer points to.

Comment: How can you make a deep copy? It is not known if the structure is homogeneous. It is not known if it is a linked list...

Comment: I was to the nature of the question. "Is it possible to do a deep copy of structure which contains a void pointer?" - yes it is possible. Is it possible to tell how many data there is without additional field - no it isn't possible, at least if it's not some kind of special data like null char terminated char* or whatever.